# Congruences between modular forms and the eigencurve construction

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, modular-forms

This question might be too conceptual.
Congruences between modular forms (due to Shimura, Hida, etc) are  really amazing. I know that the  eigencurve construction are closely related to these relations. The basic reference is "The Eigencurve" by Coleman and Mazur. Besides, I think  "A brief introduction to the work of Haruzo Hida" by Mazur is a good introduction.

It seems that we at first prove the congruence and then interpolate them into a family, like the Eisenstein family, and the property of the eigencurve are deduced from properties of modular forms.

So I wonder  conversely, can  the  eigencurve construction  explain (prove) more congruences between modular forms (not just these used in building the eigencurve)? Or other interesting facts about modular forms? For example, see section 5 of "A brief introduction to the work of Haruzo Hida".

I type slowly, sorry...

Comment: Please improve (clarify) your question by adding more detail, context, and references.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a theorem about congruences between modular forms:

*Theorem*. Let $f$ be a (normalised) eigenform of weight $k$ and level $\Gamma = \Gamma_1(N) \cap \Gamma_0(p)$. Then for any $r$, and any $k'$ sufficiently close (*) to $k$, there exists an eigenform of weight $k'$ and level $\Gamma$ that is congruent to $f$ modulo $p^r$.

This is an incredibly powerful theorem; it's virtually self-evident once you know the eigencurve exists; and I don't think I know of any way of proving it without constructing the eigencurve in the process.

Does that answer your question?

(*) Here "close" means that $k'$ has to be congruent to $k$ modulo $(p-1) p^j$, for some $j$ depending on $f$, $p$ and $r$.

Comment: Thanks, David. It seems that the eignnvariety machine really visualizes properties of modular forms. But this result seems different from the results I know (basically Shimura or  Hida's).  So is it possible to deduce  Shimura's (In A tameness criterion for Galois representations associated to modular forms (mod p) by Gross proposition 9.3 p. 478., Between weight k and weight 2) or  Hida's results (between modular forms of same wight I think)?

Comment: And is there no way prove this theorem without constructing the eigencurve? At least if $j=0$ it's just multiplying with the Hasse invariant (Eisenstein series  I mean). Maybe I shall post another MO question......

Comment: No, it is much more powerful than just multiplying by Eisenstein series, because it's showing that there are *eigenforms* of weight $k'$ highly congruent to $f$, not just any old forms of that weight.